# What does the colour green mean when applied to answers notation on the left?

Tags: discussion, answers

Still figuring out this site and came across this bit of confusion.

Screenshot:

[image: green answers]

Question: Why do some answers in the question list page appear in Green and some do not?

This is not clear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a visual cue to show the answered state. It's black with no background to show unanswered questions, green text no background to show answered ones, and green text with a green background image to show questions with an accepted answer.

[image]